# Role assignments in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, permissions, ssrs-2008, user-permissions

I have created a SSRS report. In the report viewer I saw 2 security sections

1. site settings
2. folder settings.

What is the difference between these two?

I have to give access to 2 types of users

1. Somebody having permission just only for viewing report.
2. Somebody having permissions to view reports, upload report and also modify the datasource and parameter properties in the report.

What should be the security roles I should select for adding these users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add the user :

Goto :
1) Sitesettings-->Security and click newrole assignment

[image]

2)Enter the Group or User Name and select role based on your requirement. Please see below screenshot.

[image]

Then click on OK button. Here you can see the list of Roles which are assigned to group or users.

3)   Now click on the link of Home and then click on the link of Folder Settings.

[image]

4) You will see results like following.

[image]

5)Then click on New Role Assignment and you will see like below screenshot.

[image]

6)
In that screen Enter group or user name and select roles and click ok for that users

[image]

**NOTE:**
1)**Somebody having permission just only for viewing report.**
*To see only Reprot==>Select **Browser role** only*
2)**Somebody having permissions to view reports, upload report and also modify the datasource and parameter properties in the report.**
Select "**The Publisher Role**"  and The "**My Reports Role**" for them

Answer (score 1):

While the answer of Kavin may suits your needs note that it is not 100% matching your requirements:
The **Browser** role does not have only the right to view reports and folders, it can also:

- *Manage individual subscriptions*
- *View models*
- *View resources*

The **My Reports** role can do a lot of extra things you may not want to grant:

- *Create linked reports*
- *View resources*
- *Manage resources*
- *Manage folders*
- *Manage report history*
- *Manage individual subscriptions*

The **Publisher** role have far less rights than the **My Reports** one, and will add just the *Manage models* task.

---

I think the best option you have is to create **custom roles**.
To do so with SSRS 2008, you need to connect using SQL Server Management Studio, selecting the **Reporting Services** Server type.

[image: Login]

You will be able to manage roles from there. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156293%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is a MSDN article that will help you.

Back to your requirements, I think the custom roles you should create are (name them as you wish as long as you don't use an existing name):

**Report Viewer**:

- *View reports*
- *View folders* (if you want to provide a direct link to the reports and do not want people to be able to navigate to the hierarchy, do not add this task)

**Report Manager**:

- *View reports*
- *View folders*
- *Manage reports*
- *View Data Sources*
- *Manage Data Sources*

Then go back to the site settings and they will available as any other system role.