# Can loggin only as Builtin/Administrator

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

What I've done is:

- Turned UAC policy off
- Added local/domain user to the Administrators group via localhost/Reports
- Added the user to users list of SSRS DB.

Result: I can only login to localhost/ReportServer as Adminstrator, not any other user.

Error message:

```
The permissions granted to user 'mydomain\myAccount' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)
```

However I can login to localhost/Reports and edit Site Settings.

I tried pretty everything from what I found in Google, but nothing help me out. What am I missing?

Comment: What are the SSRS security settings of the item you are trying to access?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin What do you mean? I'm trying to see my reports by other users in my network.

Comment: In `http://localhost/reports`, when you browse the item you want to see and go to `Folder Settings` or click on the arrow next to an item and click on `Security`, what are the user/groups and their associated roles?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Re-added myself in Folder settings with all Roles and now it works, thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked, but doing so is not the way to go on a production environment. If users need to be able to see reports, give them the Browser role, or better yet, create a tailored role like I explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251763/role-assignments-in-ssrs/30255963#30255963)

Comment: @SébastienSevrin, sure, I'll explore that more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add the user to Folder Settings with all roles (click Role checkbox). I knew I was missing something trivial.