# Provide a URL to access SSRS Report without going via a website or application

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to provide a weblink for a SSRS report without the need for a website or application?

I need to provide a user a URL to a report without that user having access to all the other SSRS reports and settings.

So I what to create a link this:

http://MyServer/Reports/Pages/MyReport

Comment: try http://myserver/reportserver/    and browse to it.

Comment: Yes, but then they can see all the folders

Comment: Correct, you need to change the security for the reports if you want to prevent access to other reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, here is how to do it:

- Set the security of the report you want to share and give the browser role to the user.
- Click on the report and provide the URL to the user. The URL will be of this format: `http://<YourServer>/Reports_<YourInstance>/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f<YourReportPath>`

The user won't be able to see other items if he doesn't have the appropriate rights.

You will have to do this for each report you need to provide.
If you need to disable report subscription, consider using a [custom role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251763/role-assignments-in-ssrs/30255963#30255963).

---

You can also also set the security on the parent folder if you want this to apply on all the reports.
If you need to disable the folder browsing, this can also be done with a custom role (by default the *Browser* role can *Browse*).